# How to just run an URL(php) with as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, urlloader

I am currently using:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var url:String = GameConfig.SITE_DOMAIN+"/insert_tracking_event.php?hash="+GameConfig.hashTracking+"&event_id="+event+"&check=xxxxxxx";         
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
```

It works one time and even if i reload the page it somehow dont run the url again. The only way for it to work again is cleaning cache and reloading the swf.

Is there other method or way to do it? I dont need any responses just run the url.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried appending a random number parameter to the URL, is that what that &check=xxxxxxx is for? Is blocking caching of the swf by default in the HTML an option.

Answer (score 0):

Well @user3120770 gave me the answer, all i needed was to send a random num in the url so it ll never get blocked.

```
"&randomnum=xxxxx"
```

Thanks